# How to better design the delete operation in an Android CRUD

Tags: android, kotlin, crud

I am having some questions about how to better design a crud application (specifically the delete operation) on a basic Android CRUD app

The workflow that I'm using is a RecyclerView in my MainActivity, and when I click a fab, I go to a new activity and handle the Add operation there. The same goes for the Edit operation, when I click an item in the list it goes to a new activity and I handle the deletion there.

The problem with the delete operation is that I want to implement a long item click, open a popup and do the deletion. I don't need a new activity.

So, is it better to create a new Acitivity to handle the deletion, don't display any layout, and redirect back to the MainActivity after? Or should I put the deletion logic on the MainActivity inside a onClickListener? I'm really confused on how to do this in a clean way

Comment: You can do the deletion in MainActivity, not a problem. A better approach would be to use the MVVM pattern. The mistake I did as a beginner was to start adding a lot of functionality in MainActivity and at the end of it all my MainActivity was over 1900 lines, it runs smoothly but just not maintainable.

Comment: @Ranjan Thanks! I will look into that, but the thing I'm most worried about is poluting my MainActivity with two AsyncTask inner classes (for the Read and Delete crud tasks) because I'm using Room, they should be in the MainActivity too, right?

Comment: No, make a repository/view Model class and do the dB operations there. Room supports live data so that changes can be observed and you can perform your task in separate class and still update your UI without much trouble.